# The Equation of a Plane in 3D

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been told that Ax + By + Cz + D = 0 AND Ax + By + Cz = D are both legitimate equations of a plane in 3D space.

What is the difference and how are both possible? Shouldn't the variable D in the second equation be negative?

Comment: We can redefine $D$  as $-D$ if you wish, it still stays an arbitrary constant .

Comment: That makes sense, but what does D represent in terms of the graph of the plane?

Comment: Let's say ⟨1, 2, 3⟩ was the orthogonal vector. How would D help in finding a point?

Comment: Then we have $1x+2y+3z=D$. Set $x=y=0$ then we have $3z=D$, from which you can solve for $z$ to get $(0,0,D/3)$ as a point on the plane. @C.Opuy

Comment: I apologize if my questions are redundant, but wouldn't the sign of D change the position of that point?

Comment: Yes, one would have to specify what one means by $D$. @C. Opuy

Comment: If D was -3, the z coordinate would change depending on what equation you use. In the second, it would be -1, in the first, it would be 1.

Comment: The equations are not the same, but they both are general equations of planes. $1x+2x+3y=4$ and $1x+2x+3y-4=0$ are equivalent. In this first we have $D=4$ in the second $D=-4$. @C.Opuy

Answer (score 1):

$D$ here represents how much the plane is "moved" vertically. For example, rewrite the equation as:
$$ Cz = Ax + By + D$$
And the idea is pretty similar to a $b$ in $y=ax + b$. 
$D$ can be redefined as you wish, so it doesn't make a difference at all writing it $D$ or $-D$.

Comment: But doesn't that affect where the graph is? For example, if b were -9, it would create a different line than if b were 3.

Comment: The way you write it with the arbitrary constants is completely... arbitrary. You could write $-Cz = - Ax + By - D$ and it would still be a plane equation in 3D.

Comment: Wouldn't $D/C$ be how much it "moved" vertically? Because $z=....+D/C$

Comment: Ahmed S. Attaalla Yes.

Comment: Ahmed S. Attaalla but since $C$ is a constant it would still be appropriate to consider $D$ as a "indicator" (however not te exact value) of how much the plane moved.